# Let $X$ be a metric and $A \subset X$, and let $x$ limit point of $A$

Tags: real-analysis

Show there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ of distinct points in $A -\{x\}$ such that $(x_n)$ converges to $x$.

This seems like definition, but I'm not exactly sure how to show the existence of a sequence. Here's my approach so far:

Let $B_\epsilon(x_n)$ be the open ball of radius $\epsilon$, since $x$ is a limit point, we have that $B_\epsilon(x_n) \cap (A - \{x\})$. I want to create a sequence to show that $x_n$ converges to $x$ but I'm not exactly... sure how to do it.

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko I just made it the radius of the ball.

Comment: @Pat Usually a ball has two parameters, a center and a radius, $B_r(x)$ or $B(x,r)$ are common notations. Now what you wrote seems to depend on 3 or 4 parameters and makes no sense. What should $B_d(x,x_n)$ with radius $\epsilon$ be (in usual notation)?

Comment: @AlexR Oh, my apologies. I wrote it wrong, I'll fix that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To construct such a sequence, remember that since $x$ is a limit point, the set $B_\epsilon(x) \cap (A\setminus \{x\})$ will never be empty for $\epsilon>0$. For the sequence $(x_n)$ now just chose $x_n \in (A\setminus \{x\}) \cap B_{\frac1n}(x) \ne \emptyset$. The choice is possible for the reasons stated and the sequence converges to $x$ no matter what choices we make, as can easily be shown.

Comment: Thanks, one more question. "$x_n \in (A\setminus \{x\}) \cap B_{\frac1n}(x) \ne \emptyset$", If I'm understanding this correctly the reason why why this isn't empty is because it's a neighborhood of $B_\epsilon(x) \cap (A\setminus \{x\})$?

Comment: It's a specific choice for $\epsilon$. It's not empty because it is a neighborhood of $x$ intersected with $A\setminus\{x\}$ and $x$ is a limit point of $A$.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: Ah okay, gotcha. Thank you!